# Ошибка компиляции программы через pyinstaller

Tags: python

Код работает правильно, путь прописан тоже правильно, любую программу хочу скомпилировать, выводит эту ошибку:

```
TypeError: an integer is required (got type bytes)
```

Comment: pyinstaller проще запускать из директории с проэктом, обязательны флаги -F и -w

Comment: Я написал cd "путь" -F название файла (Это правильно?)

Answer (score 0):

Случайно python не 3.8? Если да, то 
надо взять Pyinstaller-develop с Github ( ссылка есть на pypi )  и копировать папку PyInstaller из архива в Lib/site-packages/PyInstaller/ . Поможет дожить до следующего релиза :)